# Mobile software for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04

Are there any good Mobile applications available for Ubuntu where I can send sms, view sms and manage a normal Phone from Ubuntu, even syncronising with Evolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about synchronizing with evolution. But [Gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/) seems to have other features. There are some other applications as well. You can use synaptic manager and search for other similar applications.